# How to test Async calls in JEST using request without mocking and awaits for react-hooks testing library

Tags: testing, jestjs, react-hooks, automated-tests, react-hooks-testing-library

I am not good at writing tests as far as non API functionalities are concerned I have tested using JEST with the help of rendererHook Just like below **Sample correct TEST**:

```
import { render, screen, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import useAppDrawer from "../../../utils/hooks/useAppDrawer";
import {act,renderHook} from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import React from "react";

describe("hook: useAppDrawer", () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup();
    });

    test('drawer open', () => {
        const {result} = renderHook(useAppDrawer);

        act(()=>{
            result.current.handleDrawerOpen();
        })
        expect(result.current.open).toBe(true);

    });
    test('drawer close', () => {
        const {result} = renderHook(useAppDrawer);

        act(()=>{
            result.current.handleDrawerClose();
        })
        expect(result.current.open).toBe(false);

    });

});
```

But what will we do in case of API calls in JEST that is still confusing to me. I am still not able to understand that how can I test API calls in JEST like this below **Problematic function**:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import request from "../services/Http";
import useIsLoading from "./useIsLoading";
import {Context} from "../store/context/store";
import {SET_BOOTHS} from "../store/context/Constants";

export default function useFetchBooths(){

    const {isLoading, setIsLoading} = useIsLoading()
    const [{booths}, dispatch] = useContext(Context)

    function fetchBooths(){

        setIsLoading(true)

        request.get('/event/get-booth-list')
            .then((res) => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                if (res)
                {
                    dispatch({
                        type: SET_BOOTHS,
                        payload: res.data.booth_data
                    })
                }
            })
    }

    function searchBooths(value){

        if (value)
        {
            let obj = booths.filter(booth => booth.booth_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));

            if (obj.length > 0)
            {
                dispatch({
                    type: SET_BOOTHS,
                    payload: obj
                })
            }
            else
            {
                fetchBooths()
            }

        }
        else
        {
            fetchBooths()
        }
    }

    return { booths, fetchBooths, isLoading, searchBooths }
}
```

what would be the possible jest test for the above function? considering cases like if booth is fetched or not as in both cases I am getting booth value to be [].
**My attempt so far for this is:**

```
import { render, screen, cleanup, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import useFetchBooths from "../../../utils/hooks/useFetchBooths";
import {act,renderHook} from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import React from "react";
import * as requestsModule from "../../../utils/services/Http";
import {Store} from "../../../utils/store/context/store";

describe("hook: useFetchBooths", () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup();
    });

    test('Booth is fetched', async () => {
        const boothData = [
            {
                "message": "Data fetched Successfully",
                "success": true
            }
        ];
        const wrapper = ({children}) => (
            <Store>{children}</Store>
        )
        const {result } = renderHook(() => useFetchBooths(), {wrapper});
         jest.spyOn(result.current, "fetchBooths").mockResolvedValue(boothData);
         console.log(result.current.fetchBooths())
        await expect(result.current.fetchBooths()).resolves.toEqual([{ "success": true, "message": "Data fetched Successfully" }]);

    });

});
```

The above test case is passed, but this is a mocked API(I am creating data and comparing it with my own written data but this is not I want) but I want to ensure my real API is working or not in that test like I am fetching booth list in fetchBooths() function so how can I test it with mock API when my everything is dependant on real API I want to test it by checking my real API is actually working or not in that test by using some **async/await** But I am badly stuck at this point. Also, I am unable to understand **what would be the test case for searchBooths function as it is appearing undefined** and booths list appearing as [ ] although it shouldn't be [] I am still not able to figure out the solution. Please help me write these test cases

Comment: what would you like to test here? I assume you are not interested in testing `makeStyles` itself

Comment: @thedude I am still not able to understand how can we write test for API calls in JEST. Just like I have written above function fetchBooths() how can I write tests for it considering cases like if booth is fetched or not as in both cases I am getting booth value to be [].

Comment: @thedude I have updated the question. Can you plz help me now?

Comment: I would look into `jest.spyOn` to mock the `request.get` and assert that it has been called with the correct input. Same approach could be made to test `makeStyles`

Comment: @thedude can you please elaborate a bit more in like rectifying my attempted code considering my attempt above like I can get into the fetchBooths setLoading(true) but not able to get anything from a request. Let me know if possible so that I can share my screen with you?

Comment: @thedude I am badly stuck at this point from last 2 days

Comment: have you looked into using a spy to mock the response of `request.get`?

Comment: @thedude I am new to JEST testing I have read the documentation and tried for spy mock too but I am getting nothing in booths that are supposed to contain some data after the request runs successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235931/discussion-between-arslaan-muhammad-ali-and-thedude).

Answer (score 0):

In your test code use a `spy` to mock the requests module:

```
import * as requestsModule from "../services/Http";

describe("hook: useFetchBooths", () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        cleanup();
    });

    test('Booth is fetched', async () => {

        jest.spyOn(requestsModule, 'get').mockResolvedValue([]) // <-- here you should provide the data you want your hook to see.

        const wrapper = ({children}) => (
            <Store>{children}</Store>
        )

        const {result } = renderHook(() => useFetchBooths(), {wrapper});
        await act(async () => {
            await waitFor(() => result.current.fetchBooths() )
        })

        await act(async () => {
            await waitFor(() => result.current.booths )
            console.log(result.current);
        })
        expect(result.current.booths).toEqual([]);

    });

});
```

Update: how to mock useContext

1. create a custom hook

```
// boothsContext.js

import {Context} from "../store/context/store";

export const useBoothsContext = () => useContext(Context)
```

2. mock the hook using `jest.spyOn`:

```
import { wait } from '@testing-library/react'
import * as BoothsContextModule from './boothsContext.js'

...

test('Booth is fetched', async () => {
    const mockDispatch = jest.fn()
    const data = { booths: []} // change this to inject different data into your hook result
    jest.spyOn(BoothsContextModule, 'useBoothsContext')
        .mockReturnValue([data, mockDispatch])

    // perform test steps

   await wait(() => expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      type: SET_BOOTHS,
      payload: {...} // <-- expected payload you want to assert
   }))
```

Comment: can't I just put a check on something like if data is fetched and get    "message": "Data fetched Successfully", then I just pass the test ? how should I achieve this here in JEST?

Comment: I am passing the data like         jest.spyOn(requestsModule, 'get').mockResolvedValue({data:{"success": true,
                "message": "Data fetched Successfully"},"booth_data": [
                {
                    "booth_id": "8818",
                    "booth_name": "Advanis changed",
                }]
        }); but I am getting caught into error " Error: Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function; undefined given instead "

Comment: how will I compare these mocked values with the actual one in order to add the "expect condition" to pass by comparing original data with the mocked data? Can you please update the answer both for searchBooths and fetchBooths function including the expected condition which should be met in order to pass the test I shall be greatly thankful to you. If you ask I can share my screen with you through TeamViewer or something

Comment: I am still stuck I have updated my attempt according to your guidance and I have a question as well if we are just mocking the API then how will we just test the actual real API is working or not like I also want to ensure my real API is working in that function test that's my main concern by using some sort of async-await. Also what will be the test case for searchBooths function I am confused in writing that test as well I have mentioned this file in question with the bold name "Problematic Function" for which I want to write the test. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems like you are not really writing unit tests. The best practice is to break apart your code into units that can be tested separately. 
If you want to actually call you API, then instead of mocking the get requests you can mock the `useContext` hook and check if the correct `dispatch` call was made

Comment: yeah exactly thats what I am looking for how can I use mock the useContext and get know if dispatch call was made can you please help me by rewriting your answer according to this? For searchBooths and fetchBooths that would be extremely helpful for me

Comment: what sort of data should I put here  const data = { booths: []}  like my own custom created data which I created manually without any response? such as         const boothData = [
            {
                "booth_id": "8818",
                "booth_name": "Advanis changed",
            }
        ];

Comment: and what should I add in  payload: {...} it is popping out as undefined. Let me know if possible so that I can share my screen with you

Comment: I am getting this error Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: {"payload": [{"booth_id": "8818", "booth_name": "Advanis changed"}], "type": "SET_BOOTHS"}

Number of calls: 0

Comment: can you please look into my question above and let me know according to Problematic function which is in bold, its test case

Comment: please join me in the chat room